# Forcing WaitForDebugEvent to execute a certain thread

Tags: multithreading, debugging, winapi

I am writing a windows debugger, so I have the usual ContinueDebugEvent/WaitForDebugEvent loop:

```
while (true)
{
 ContinueDebugEvent(hTargetProcessId, hTargetThreadId, lastDebugResult);
 WaitForDebugEvent(&evt, INFINITE);
 ...
 hTargetThreadId = evt.dwThreadId;
}
```

This works fine, but I'm in the process of adding a feature which requires the ability to execute a specific thread mid-debugging. To do this, I suspend all threads I'm not interested in, like this (I've omitted a load of code for brevity - hope this is clear enough!):

```
while (true)
{
 if (onlyACertainThread)
 {
  for (int n=0; n<threadcount; n++)
   if(threads[n] != certainThread)
    SuspendThread(threads[n]);
 }

 ContinueDebugEvent(hTargetProcessId, hTargetThreadId, lastDebugResult);
 WaitForDebugEvent(&evt, INFINITE);

 if (onlyACertainThread)
 {
  for (int n=0; n<threadcount; n++)
   if(threads[n] != certainThread)
    ResumeThread(threads[n]);
 }
 ...
 (code to add to 'threads', update threadcount, decide if we want to restrict to a certain thread, etc)
 ...
 hTargetThreadId = evt.dwThreadId;
}
```

However, I often see debug events from the wrong thread. For example:

- Thread A is running
- Decide we want to observe thread B; suspend thread A, call continue/waitfordebugevent(.. A.pid..)
- Get debug notifications (breakpoints, exceptions) from thread A.

What I want is for the final step to be 'get notifications from B'. I've tried calling WaitForDebugEvent(..B.pid..) which doesn't work.

Is this expected behaviour?

My suspicion is that thread suspend/resume counters are only observed by the kernel when at thread is being scheduled; ie, at the end of a timeslice. This would cause thread A to continue running until its current timeslice is up. Can anyone confirm/deny this idea? If so.. how would I work around it? My best idea at the moment is to 'inject' an artificial call to Sleep(0) after I suspend a thread, but I really don't want to do that unless I have to!

If it's any difference, the machine I run on is a single-threaded XP box.

Comment: MSDN:'If the function succeeds, execution of the specified thread is suspended and the thread's suspend count is incremented'.  I would be very, very surprised if SuspendThread() returns before the target thread has been removed from the set of running/ready threads. There is no mention of waiting until the next, unrelated interrupt that exits via the scheduler. On one core, you're guaranteed that the target thread is not running, if the target thread is running on another core, SuspendThread() would cause the core to be hardware-interrupted to suspend the thread.

Comment: But that's exactly how it works, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150205-00/?p=44743

Comment: Wow, I have no idea how I've gone so long without knowing that (and I read oldnewthing, too). I bet that was the source of my problem.. !! Thanks for pointing that out.